# Bird wings not flapping with three.js canvas geometry birds

Tags: three.js

I give the canvas a transparent background with the code below so that it looks like the birds are flying over a landscape. But when I do this the wings on the birds no longer flap. What am I doing wrong?

```
renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
renderer.setClearColor(0x000000, 0);
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({alpha: true, canvas: birdscanvas});
```

If I comment out

```
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({alpha: true, canvas: birdscanvas});
```

the bird wings flap.

[Example here](https://jsfiddle.net/brewpixels/pa9goL2f/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it as follows

```
  renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer({
    alpha: true,
    canvas: birdscanvas
  });
  renderer.setClearColor(0x000000, 0);
  renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
  // renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ alpha: true, canvas: birdscanvas });
```

For WebGLRenderer based, do it as follows;

```
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    alpha: true,
    canvas: birdscanvas
  });
  renderer.setClearColor(0x000000, 0);
  renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
```

And in the `render` method, add the below line at end of the for loop;

```
  bird.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
```

Comment: This is the best [tag:three.js] answer ever.

Comment: Is there a way to get the wings to flap with a WebGLRenderer?

Comment: @MonsterWimp757 I've updated the answer for `WebGLRenderer` based solution.